# Is there any difference between the following sentences?

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference

> 1. It's the first time I've seen him that happy.
> 2. It's the first time I see him that happy.

Are these two sentences correct?
If they are, what's the difference between them?

Comment: Both are correct sentences.

Answer (score -1):

Neither sound correct to me, due to tense.

To me, the two idiomatic phrases would be:

Present tense, while you are in the person’s presence:

> **It’s** the first time **I’ve** seen him **this** happy.

Past tense:

> **It was** the first time **I’d** seen him **that** happy.

Comment: The only difference between your first suggestion and the OP's first suggestion is _**this** happy_ vs. _**that** happy_, respectively. Both are completely fine. "This happy" is more appropriate if the person's happiness is also perceptible to the listener at the present time (e.g., when they are all in the same room); otherwise "that" probably makes more sense.

Comment: I agree that the OP's second suggestion sounds unnatural, although it is in fact completely grammatical and one can imagine a contrived scenario where it works, such as two actors discussing scenes in a play: "Act III is the first time I see him that happy."

Comment: Imagine I am driving a car and my friend is in the car. What is the correct saying: "It's the first time I am driving a car" or "It's the first time I drive a car"?

Comment: In alignment with the first example in my answer, it’s actually: It’s the first time I’ve driven a car.

Comment: More natural in my opinion would be "this is my first time driving a car."

Comment: @TypelA, yes I know. Chris Mack has given me his answer, but I need your confirmation. Which sentence would be correct in my situation: it's the first time I drive/am driving/have driven a car?

Comment: I’m reality, I’d either use “this is the first time I’ve driven a car” or “this is my first time driving a car”.

Comment: @TypeIA Your thinking is unconventional. Chris deserves some props here.

Comment: @AlexRaw The answer as it stands now is flatly wrong. It says neither of the OP's suggestions sound correct. In fact they both are (though alternatives certainly exist), and a better answer would examine this in more detail as I've tried to do in my comments.